# Is it a good practice to separate roles with 'usage' permissions on data warehouse compute from other roles which provide access to databases?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

With the ability to allow secondary roles, is it a good practice to separate roles with 'usage' permissions on data warehouse compute from other roles which provide access to databases, schemas. tables? As example, I create a role called 'USE_DEV_DW". This role is granted usage to the DEV data warehouse compute. In parallel, I create a role that has usage on a specific set of databases and schemas. I then grant both roles to a user so that they can query the provided database tables using the separately provided compute (data warehouse). This way I can control what compute users have access to separate from what objects they can query. I don't see this being possible without the ability to provide for secondary roles? Looking to see if others have done something like this.

Answer (score 1):

Even though there is no guidelines from Snowflake how to create the roles, the way you described makes sense.

When you have two layers of roles, let's call them *database* and *functional*,
it will be easier to create role hierarchies and assign them to users.

For illustration purposes assuming you have **DEVELOPERS** and **ANALYSTS** as your groups and you have **SALES** and **PRODUCTS** databases

You can create your roles and role hierarchies like this

*Database Roles*

```
R_DB_SALES_READ_WRITE
R_DB_SALES_READ

R_DB_PRODUCTS_READ_WRITE
R_DB_PRODUCTS_READ
```

*Functional Roles*

```
R_DEVELOPER
R_ANALYSTS
```

*Role Hiercharchy*

```
R_DEVELOPER
  R_DB_SALES_READ_WRITE
  R_DB_PRODUCTS_READ_WRITE

R_ANALYSTS
  R_DB_SALES_READ
  R_DB_PRODUCTS_READ
```

With this you only need to assign functional roles to users

Comment: Actually the concept of **functional** and  **access**  roles is well described in the documentation [Aligning Object Access with Business Functions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-considerations.html#aligning-object-access-with-business-functions)

Comment: Hi.   The Snowflake documentation does indeed discuss separation of 'functional' and data 'access' roles and how you can build a role hierarchy.  However, it does not come out and say much about this in regard to 'usage' permissions to compute (data warehouse).   Seems to me that these should be separate because access to database objects I see as different from what compute you are allowed to use.  For example. I may not want certain user groups (roles)  consuming XL compute clusters but they may have access to all DEV environment databases.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda Looks like documentation is updated with this addition since last time I checked.